# Will any $L$ and $M$ belonging to $Del_X(r,R)$ be roughly equivalent?

Tags: geometry

Let $(X,d)$ be $R^n$ with Euclidean norm. On the set of closed subsets - $C(X)$ of the space $(X,d)$, consider the Fell topology on $C(X)$. It is well known that in such a topology $C(X)$ is a Hausdorff compact space. Consider a subset of $C(X)$ - Delone sets with fixed parameters $r, R$, notation - $Del_X(r,R)$. $Del_X(r,R)$ is closed in $C(X)$ with the Fell topology, which means compact. We define the property of rough equivalence of Delone sets as follows $L$ and $M$, there is a bijection $φ:L->M$ and the homeomorphism $ψ:[0,inf)->[0,inf)$ such that the following properties are satisfied: $d(x,y)<=ψ(d(φ(x),φ(y))$ and
$d(φ(x),φ(y))<=ψ(d(x,y))$ for any $x,y$. Then $Del_X(r,R)$ is divided into equivalence classes.

**Question:**
Will any $L$ and $M$ belonging to $Del_X(r,R)$ be roughly equivalent? If the answer to this question is negative, will equivalence classes be open in the sense of the induced Fell topology on $Del_X(r,R)$?

In fact, I came across this question while solving another one. I tried to bypass it by introducing the Vietoris topology instead of the Fell topology, and this method really solves some problems, but there is also a more global obstacle that cannot be bypassed, because $Del_X(r,R)$ ceases to be compact. I'm almost sure that at least one of my questions has the answer yes, but unfortunately I'm not well versed in rough geometry and I don't even have any ideas how to solve these problems.